# How to add pagination and extra links in response?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am using ASP.NET core 1.1, and I am currently creating a Rest API.

In order to respect the conventions of a Rest architecture, I would like to add pagination and extra information before sending response.

This is my controller:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetUniversities")]
public IEnumerable<University> GetUniversities()
{
      return _univRepository.GetAll();
}
```

GetAll():

```
public IEnumerable<University> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Universities.ToList();
}
```

Actually, what I wanna do is to render something like this.

[JSON reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLcgD.png)

But I don't know how to generate this kind of data dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a take method available, that you can utilize to do pagination. how to call these pages depends on how you configure your routes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by extra information. But, you could build a view model to send information back to the user. That way you can tag along any other information you need to send in the response. Here is a simple example to get you started with pagination. You can obviously flow this down to your repository as well.

```
 [HttpGet()]
 [Route("api/GetUniversities/Page/{page:int}")]
 public IEnumerable<University> GetUniversities(int page)
  {
    return _univRepository.GetAll().Skip(page*10).Take(10);
  }
```

The above is assuming that you are sending back 10 at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. Actually what I wanna do is edting my GetUniversities() method so that I could render something like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLcgD.png .What my method do now is redring my list of universities in JSON.

Comment: Everything that you show in the image can be done by just flowing the current page number into your repository method and a viewModel represented by the json in your screen shot.